# Comprimir solo archivo especifico Python

Tags: python, zip

Saludos estoy intentando comprimir un archivo XML en formato ZIP para lo cual le doy la ruta absoluta, mi código:

```
import os
import zipfile

PATH_XML = 'media/Facturacion/miarchivo.xml'
PATH_COMPLETO_XML =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),PATH_XML)

 PATH_ZIP = 'media/Facturacion/archivozipnuevo.zip'
 PATH_COMPLETO_ZIP = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),PATH_ZIP)

zipfile.ZipFile(PATH_COMPLETO_ZIP, mode='w').write(PATH_COMPLETO_XML)
```

Este código efectivamente comprimir el archivo final pero con todos los subdirectorios que halla en dicha ruta, y solo deseo que contenga dicho archivo final.

Gracias por sus sugerencias..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para evitar que te genere toda la estructura del árbol de archivos debes usar el argumento `arcname` del método [`zipfile.ZipFile.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) y pasar el nombre del archivo a incluir:

```
import os
import zipfile

PATH_SCRIPT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PATH_XML = 'media/Facturacion/miarchivo.xml'
PATH_COMPLETO_XML =  os.path.join(PATH_SCRIPT, PATH_XML)

PATH_ZIP = 'media/Facturacion/archivozipnuevo.zip'
PATH_COMPLETO_ZIP = os.path.join(PATH_SCRIPT, PATH_ZIP)

with zipfile.ZipFile(PATH_COMPLETO_ZIP, mode='w') as file:
    file.write(PATH_COMPLETO_XML, arcname=os.path.basename(PATH_COMPLETO_XML))
```

De no especificar una ruta absoluta `filename` se trata como una ruta relativa al directorio de trabajo actual. Toda la estructura de archivos a partir de dicho directorio de trabajo hasta llegar al archivo que queremos incluir es reproducida en el zip (si no se especifica `arcname`). Si asignas una ruta absoluta ocurre lo mismo, pero generando toda la estructura de ficheros de la ruta absoluta.

Por lo tanto, obviamene si cambias el directorio de trabajo (`os.chdir`) de tu proceso al que contiene el archivo a incluir (`media/Facturacion`), puedes pasar a `filename` solo el nombre del archivo (`"miarchivo.xml"`) y no necesitas de `arcname`.

Comment: es posible tambien realizarlo asi "zipfile.ZipFile(PATH_COMPLETO_ZIP, mode='w').write(PATH_COMPLETO_XML,arcname=os.path.basename(PATH_COMPLETO_XML) )"..? es decir sin el with..gracias de antemano

Comment: Si, el `with` es solo para que se cierre el archivo de forma automática y segura (incluso si hay excepciones de por medio). Puedes quitar el `with` pero por norma general es buena practica cerrar el archivo explícitamente cuando se termine con él, bien llamado a `file.close()` o mejor usando el administrador de contexto  (`with`) y no dejar esto al recolector de basura.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta muy completa..!!